# more enum in interface

Tags: java, enums

Check this example:

```
public interface IConstants {

    public enum Levels {
        LOW("30 points"), MEDIUM("50 points")

    };

    public enum Cars {
        PORSCHE("250 km/h"), FORD("180 km/h")
    }

}
```

I'd like to have an interface like this, because I want to access my enums this way:

```
    String level = IConstants.Levels.MEDIUM;
    String car = IConstants.Cars.PORSCHE;
```

The compiler shows this message:

> constructor IConstants."enum name" is undefined.

Solved this way :

```
 public class Constants {

        public static class Levels {
            public static String LOW = "30 points"; 
            public static String MEDIUM = "50 points";
        };

//... other classes

    }
```

-useful for me in (my case) to have a "tree" in my constants, every constant starting by keyword Constants then subcategory and then value -> `Constants.Levels.LOW`.
//critize it if it's very bad practise, i agree all comments
-another maybe good thing that there will be all constants in one class

Comment: This is the [Constant Interface Antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface). Don't do this.

Comment: OK so I should declare all my constants in class instead of interface? public final class Constants {...} ??

Comment: Why declare an `enum` as a nested class at all? What do you gain?

Comment: because all my constants would be in different enum, as I wrote: String level = IConstants.Levels.MEDIUM instead of IConstants.MEDIUM for example, then there will be levels and cars shuffled together

Comment: And what's wrong with `Levels.MEDIUM`? I'm not sure you understand yourself what you want or what you are trying to achieve. Please begin by reading [the Oracle tutorial on `enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: I know that that's the best practise, but in my case it's better to finding constants this way: if i write IConstants then dot, the IDE shows me all subcategories of constants = Levels, Cars etc..

Comment: Laziness is never an excuse for poor programming practice. Sure it should be obvious that many people had exactly the same thought as you, then the majority of the Java community decided that the costs exceeded any gains. Learn from other's mistakes or you are doomed to repeat them.

Comment: No, it's not about laziness, I wrote it a little wrong, I just want to have something like a tree in my constants, it's just about the IConstants keyword before the enum, but I solved it using static nested class, I'll post my solution to the topic,critize it then if it will be very bad move, thanks

Comment: Another thing to point out is that there is no convention for beginning Java interface names with `I` - it is not considered appropriate by most of the Java community.

Comment: yes I know that, I'm not doing it in other interfaces, I thought it will just suite for this example, but it was bad, thx

Answer (score 1):

Like Boris the spider told you in comment declaring constants in interfaces is an anti pattern. However your problem comes from the fact that you are passing a String to any instance of your enum but you are not declaring a constructor for this

```
public enum Levels {
    LOW("30 points"), MEDIUM("50 points")

    private final String pts;
    private Levels(String pts) {
       this.pts = pts;
    }

    public String getPoints() {
       return pts;
    }

};
```

This should work.

Comment: is the way I've solved it very bad practise ? (see edited post), thanks

Comment: @CharlieHarper No the way you solved it isn't bad practice, but you should also make the `Level` class final and the use static imports.

Comment: @CharlieHarper now it is better since you're not using anymore an interface as container of the constants. You could also leave the enums in a class with a private constructor. I honestly prefer enums for holding constants but there is nothing wrong in your choice

Comment: @msrd0 yes I know i forgot to add final keyword to the classes, thx for notion guys.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing constructors in both enums. A private variable and the constructor is required, e.g.

```
public enum Levels {
     private String name;
     public Levels(String name) {
          this.name = name;
     } 
}
```

Also it is considered bad practice to put inner classes, constants in interfaces.

Comment: is the way I've solved it very bad practise ? (see edited post), thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add to other answers, it will still not compile after an enum constructor is added, because you are assigning a `String` variable to a `Levels` or `Cars`. Please use:

```
String level = IConstants.Levels.MEDIUM.methodToAccessString();
String car = IConstants.Cars.PORSCHE.methodToAccessString();
```

Replacing `methodToAccessString()` with whatever you call it, of course.

Comment: is the way I've solved it very bad practise ? (see edited post), thanks